# mysql database order by

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

```html
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>sum(value)</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>null</td>
            <td>85</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>arun</td>
            <td>74</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dhin</td>
           <td>55</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
```

i have a table datas like above. I wanto sort items based sum(value) desc and if the name is null it has to be shown last. how to write query in mysql

my query is SELECT p.class,p.buyref,p.no_of_mat_id,p.tot_cos from (select a.class,group_concat(distinct a.buyref SEPARATOR '","' ) as buyref,count(*) as no_of_mat_id,sum(tc) as tot_cos from (select a.class,a.buyref,sum(b.total_cost) as tc from (SELECT distinct a.class,b.buyref FROM `material_master` a join `rxml_reference` b on a.cat_id=b.cat_id where a.language='0161-1#LG-000001#1' and b.property='BUYER REFERENCE' and b.buyref<>'' and b.buyref in ("E268200006","E570500008","E330010072","1274266","1257657","1216933","1275795","1269085","1216931","1257656","1213833","5066725","1275794","5067252","1257658","1236240","1274249","1213824","1275797","5067664","1236239","1248625","1275796","5066724","5065949","1213989","1216932","1257659","1227545","1280565","1280549","1213829","1264792","1280550","1280551","1216943","1249846","1210250","1282003","1248620","5065948","1213830","1216942","1210217","1210247","1279855","1280567","1280553","1210292","1281546","1213846","1238253","1210323","1264791","5065610","1217304","1216973","1271479","1285240","1217303","5063937","5063934","1285241","1238255","1280552","1280566","1292638","5075432","1292635","1293721","1258418","1290188","5071130","1292061","1258417","1292634","1292631","1292632","1292633","1292639","1292060","5071580","1293251","5075431","1292597","36066","1268083","1219900","49194","46646","1272051","48743","1219891","49604","41693","1247650","1241850","41728","49588","1258736","44917","1219898","1266629","39660","1267486","1270445","1222352","1259901","36074","1272388","1275153","1240833","1237806","46645","1219897","1271400","1272385","41066","36073","1244303","1241848","41730","1220612","45332","41565","49204","1244246","45329","1272384","1222919","1231947","1225515","1272052","1271399","49664","46118","1241847","49691","1219899","1273498","52919","46350","49201","1272750","1237807","29632","1220800","36481","41709","1276924","40133","36062","36268","49684","1273492","1276923","36302","1281374","49603","1219892","49480")) a join final_transaction b on a.buyref=b.item where b.accounting_date >= '2014-1-01 00:00:00' and b.accounting_date <= '2018-4-31 00:00:00' and b.supplier_id in ('GLOBL-ASP01-0000005443','GLOBL-ASP01-0000005443','GLOBL-NFT01-0000124166','GLOBL-ASP01-0000001239','APCPM-APCPM-A0012496','GLOBL-ASP01-0000001643','ACM_388437','ACM_11590352','ACM_5174231','ECM_18494') group by a.class,a.buyref)a group by a.class order by sum(tc) desc) p ORDER BY p.tot_cos desc

Comment: Maybe show your mysql tables which you are using?

Comment: if your question is "How to write query in MySQL ?" then the answer is : This is not a free programming lesson site, go check some tutorials. But I suppose your question is just bad written, and you ask "What is the query for doing that ?" then the answer is : this site is not here to do your job, provide what you've tried and why you think it should work and why you think it don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT name,SUM(value) 
FROM TABLE1
ORDER BY CASE WHEN name IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,SUM(value) Desc
```

**output**

```
name    sum_value
trun    84
arun    74
dhin    55
(null)  85
```

Demo Link

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa6eb7/1